# 1C: проблемы с количеством лицензий

Tags: 1с, hasp

На 2008R2 крутится сетевой хасп ключ на 50 пользователей. Но почему-то активных максимум 20. Остальным пишется

> `ключ не найдендостигнуто максимальное количество пользователейключ не найден`

Answer (score 1):

Кроме прописывания адреса сервера лицензий для каждого клиента, проблема возможно связана с падениями 1С у клиентов. При аварийном завершении предприятия лицензии продолжают висеть. Единственный вариант это перезапускать сервис Hasp License Manager'а (Hasp Loader он называется). Следует иметь в виду, что все клиенты, подключенные в данный момент отвалятся, поэтому стоит уведомить их. Простейший вариант:

**cmd.exe**

```
net send * "Сейчас отвалится 1С"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
net stop "HASP Loader" 
net start "HASP Loader" 
net send * "Все, можно заходить в 1С"
```

Для определения занятых/свободных лицензий можно пользоваться Aladdin Monitor. Подробная информация о настройке, диагностике и решению возникающих проблем описана в документе [Инструкция по эксплуатации программных продуктов «1C» и ключей защиты HASP](http://www.aladdin-rd.ru/upload/Working_with_HASP_and_1C.pdf) (на сайте Аладдина).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать вручную где находится сетевой ключ, файл:

**C:\Program Files\1cv82\conf\nethasp.ini**

```
NH_SERVER_ADDR = <ip>
; IP addresses of all the NetHASP     
; License Managers you want to search.    
; Unlimited addresses and multiple    
; lines are possible.    
;    
; Possible address format examples:    
;  IP address:      192.114.176.65    
;  Local Hostname:  ftp.aladdin.co.il
```

Comment: еще варианты? ставим эмулятор - всё ок.<br />ЗЫ ключи тоже в порядке.